# List vertical align text middle with list-style-image

Tags: html, css, list

I am trying to vertically align some text within a list li and having issues. 
First off you need to know that I have replaced my list-style-image with a custom image. This is my CSS:

```
ul.cogs li { 
    list-style-image: url(Images/li_cog.png); 
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px; 
}
```

I tried to see if there was a way of getting the text to align to the middle.
I tried:

> vertical-align: middle;

which didn't work, so then I tried:

> line-height: 50px;

which also did not work, so I tried:

> display: table

which worked, but the image disappears from the list item....

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work?

Comment: **FYI:** `vertical-align` property will work for `table` or `table-cell`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The issue using `list-style-image` is that you cannot align with the text, the best thing to do is to use `background-image` for `li` element, and then use `padding-left` for your `li` elements.

<s>[**Buggy Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gc9LC/1/)</s> *(The issue which you are facing)*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gc9LC/)

```
ul li {
    background-image: url(http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/2222/gloss_basic/32/bullet_black.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}

ul {
    margin: 50px;
}
```

Comment: If you use `min-height` instead of `line-height` then the line spacing between the text in the `<li>` when it wraps to the next line will stay the same as the other text on your page. But when it's a single line, and the bullet image is bigger than the line-height, it will not overlap the bullet in the next `<li>`

Answer (score 16):

you can have

```
<li><span style="top:-5px; position:relative;">
```

Text shifted 5px upper

Comment: This moves both the text and the image.

Comment: This solution worked great for my needs. 
Seems like it'd be a common issue - thanks for sharing!

Comment: @machineghost no it doesn't because it's not `li` that has the style but a nested `span`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
ul.cogs li {
    list-style-image: url(Images/li_cog.png); 
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px;  
    position: relative;
}

ul li span {
    position: absolute;
    top: (x)px;
    left: (x)px;
}
```