# line-height image centered middle

Tags: css

I have this codepen : 
https://codepen.io/stephendesjardins/project/editor/ZyamgR

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url(icon.svg);
  vertical-align:middle;
}

<svg version="1.1" id="ic-puce" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="6px" height="6px"
     viewBox="0 0 6 6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 6 6;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:black;}
</style>
<circle class="st0" cx="3" cy="3" r="3"/>
</svg>
```

It replaces the list type image by an svg, but for some reason it is not aligned in the center.

I don't want to use the before **content method** or the **background-image method** so the solution needs to be outside of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427199/list-vertical-align-text-middle-with-list-style-image

Comment: it's not because i'm asking to not add background images or content as a solution

Comment: And why you don't want to use background or content since they are the only solution?

Comment: making a ui framework and I need to add these styles to ul, so all the other components would need extra css

Comment: if you add any line-height to the text in the `li`s it does not look so wrong even tho the image will always be baseline to the text.

Comment: why is it baseline with the text, is that a glitch with chrome?