# Vertically center li item to ul icon

Tags: html, css

I've added custom image as my ul, however I can't center vertically the text with the icon, it just stays at the bottom. Could someone advise how to deal with this?

Tried adding display flex and align items center to ul, but it wont work.

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Program</li>
</ul>
```

```
.list {
    list-style-image: url('img/list-circle.png');
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to use the solutions from this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427199/list-vertical-align-text-middle-with-list-style-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427199/list-vertical-align-text-middle-with-list-style-image)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
li div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
height: 100%;
}
```

maybe if you have a div in the li that is 100% high you can center content inside using flex.

```
<ul class="list">
  <li><div>Program</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When I try this then the icon disapears

Comment: what about now?

Comment: Still same, I think I wont use list for this anymore

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using `list-style-image` you cannot select the image in the style sheet to align with the text. A solution would be to use `background-image` for the `li` element and then use `padding-left` for your `li`.

```css
ul.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

ul.list li {
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/25/000/fff);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>Program</li>
</ul>
```